# Re-Enable Apple Java 6 SE from Command Line?

Tags: macos, java

So, I broke Java Preferences.app.  I'm on Mountain Lion. I had Java 6 SE (the Apple-distributed JDK/JRE) and Oracle's Java 7u10 preview. Trying to get a stub app to launch with Java 7, I unchecked the Java 6 SE checkboxes in Java Preferences.app. Now not only will my stub app not launch, but Java Preferences.app won't launch (it says there's no valid JRE 1.4+ available).  I understand this is probably because Apple's Java launcher stub is not compatible with 7u10 -- not sure how to manually re-enable SE 6, though.

Comment: I'm hoping you are running 10.6 and not a newer version of OS X since the java waters are quite muddy with Apple removing functionality and having a lot of downloads to confuse us all.

Comment: Initially muddy, yes. On the plus side, [Oracle's effective separation of the Java applet plug-in from the rest of the Java Runtime Environment may be welcomed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70498/8546) ….

Comment: The accepted answer to [How to reinstall Java 6 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72382/8546) involves a sequence of commands.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are needed worst case (and assuming you are still on 10.6 Snow Leopard):

1. [Re-download the SE 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573) and install it
2. Manually enable browser plug in if you care to have that functionality:

> ```
>  ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin"
>  ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
> ```

There is great coverage of the how and why I came up with these steps from Rich Trouton's blog:

- [Re-enable the Apple Java 6 plug-in for use with web browsers](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/re-enable-the-apple-java-6-plug-in-for-use-with-web-browsers/)
- [Java for OS X 2012-006 and Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 11](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/java-for-os-x-2012-006-and-java-for-mac-os-x-10-6-update-11/)

Apple also has similar steps in their KB article about the move from SE 6 to 7 here:

- [Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)

Comment: The link to Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 11 (Java 6 Update 37 for Snow Leopard) is no longer appropriate since the opening poster has confirmed his use of Mountain Lion. For OS X Lion v10.7 or later, for the same version of Java: [Java for OS X 2012-006](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Answer (score 1):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69670/8546 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70418/8546 refer to Apple article HT5559, modified 2012-10-22:

**[Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)**

> to disable Java 7 and re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 plug-in

- three commands
- a fourth command to re-enable Apple's Java SE 6 Web Start.