# Yosemite keeps asking to install Java runtime, while it's installed

Tags: macos, install, java

I was prompted to install JRE version 8 after upgrading to Yosemite on the family 2010 21" iMac. After I installed it (and checked whether the correct version was installed on the site of Oracle) it prompted that it wasn't installed although it was. I tried just following the steps they gave me to install it, but to no avail. Yosemite still asks to install the JRE on restart.

Does anyone know where the problem is or how I could solve it?

Comment: How did you install it and what exactly did you install?

Comment: It seems to be CS5 that's the culprit.

Comment: What is CSS to do with Java?

Comment: Adobe creative suite 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the version of Java verified by Oracle differ from the version shown at the command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/why-does-the-version-of-java-verified-by-oracle-differ-from-the-version-shown-at)

Comment: @Mark - this question is entirely different than the duplicate you referenced.

Comment: No it is not as the answer is the same which is the definition of a duplicate  - you need the JDK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the SDK instead of the JRE.

I had a similar issue: I installed the JRE and ran the webpage-based test that said I installed successfully. But my java-based app wouldn't run, and running `java -version` in the console said Java was not installed. On a whim I decided to install the full SDK and now it all works.

Comment: Exactly what I just did... :) glad to know it's not that fat of a chance... :)

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a page [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) where you can download an updated version of Java.

More information can be found from this oracle help page:

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#yosemitejava

Comment: Seems promising, but I can't load the support.apple.com page, It stays blank for some reason.

Comment: I get that sometimes with those kb/ links Try going to http://www.apple.com/support/ & pasting the kb number into search instead.

Comment: It is working here - otherwise here is the direct link to the dmg-file: http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg

Comment: I can't remember which, but I have found that clearing cache/cookies helps with support.apple.com not loading.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue on Yosemite and El Capitan, when some software requires the deprecated version of Java 6 shipped with earlier versions of OS X.

Information from Apple about this issue:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Oracle has a page about the issue here:
https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/yosemite_java.xml

You need to download and install the legacy Java 6 provided by apple, from the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing JRE 1.8, I couldn't get Java to work from the terminal 
on OS X El Capitan.

[image]

So I copied the path found in the "Java Control Panel" and created a link.

```
sudo ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" /usr/local/bin/java
```

java -version now yields

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```