# How to properly install Java in OS X

Tags: macos, java

- When I look at System Preferences > Java > Update, I see

  > Your system has the recommended version of Java.
  >   Java 7 Update 79
- From Terminal, `java -version`:

  > java version "1.7.0_71"
  >   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
  >   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
- From Terminal, `export`:

  > JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home"
- In addition to that, I also have the Java from Apple/Oracle installed as well (when first prompted to install when opening a Java-based app when there's no Java yet installed)

**Questions:**

1. Is Java 7 Update 79 == jdk1.7.0._71.jdk? Or are these separate?
2. When running some thing with Java, there is always the following:

   > objc[63077]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
   >   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
   >   and
   >   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
   >   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I'd be more than willing starting from scratch had I understood the steps to do that properly (remove, re-install). If it matters, am running OS X 10.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the version of Java verified by Oracle differ from the version shown at the command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70497/why-does-the-version-of-java-verified-by-oracle-differ-from-the-version-shown-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences shows the Java used for web applets and java -version the one found by /usr/bin/java

To get the latter install the JDK not the JRE

Comment: Okay. Downloading "Java SE Development Kit 7u79" for OS X.

Comment: After installing it, "java -version" still shows _71. I suppose that is because of the JAVA_HOME path?

Comment: We need to get more accurate on the correct download path Oracle has really messed this yp

Comment: After updating JAVA_HOME, "java -version" now showing _79, so that's up-to-date now. However the error mentioned in question #2 remains.

Comment: That should be a separate question - and I think the answer is not use JAVA_HOME - use /usr/libexec/java_home

Comment: You mean use "/usr/libexec/java_home" as the path value for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Looks to be an open bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022291

Comment: This is a horrible bug.. it wont go away

Comment: @IdanAdar this should be two questions as I have answered one and the other question leads to a sparer answer re the bug

Answer (score 1):

The following generally works for Java, versions 8 through 17.

`brew install java` may not be the best way to install Java.

Java JDK should be unzipped into a folder identifying it, withing `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` . I usually either manually download JDK and unzip it into the above folder OR install it via `jenv` command. The former gives you more control.

Then you should have `jenv` installed and have this in your `.bash_profile` :

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

Don't install Java with brew . Instead: `brew install jenv` . Then, [install Java (OR link to your installed java) using jenv](https://www.jenv.be/).