# Why does Java SE 6 Web Start (javaws) not find the JRE with Apple's Java for OS X 2012-006 on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, command-line, java

## In brief

The JRE is installed but **`javaws` can not find** the JRE.

What can I do on the command line to re-enable the web plugin for Apple's Java 6 in Chrome or Safari?

I want to avoid Java 7. (We're awaiting Java 8.)

### Detail

I have a fresh upgrade of Mountain Lion (10.8.2). I have installed JDK V6 from Apple ([Java for OS X 2012-006](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)). Now:

- all of my Java apps run fine
- **the Internet plug-in no longer works** in Chrome or Safari.

`javaws` at the command line reports:

> `No JRE present`

When a web applet is clicked:

- the operating system directs me to install a JRE
- the link goes nowhere because the JRE is already installed.

#### History

1. Upgraded to Mountain Lion
2. Forced JRE install through `java -version` method.  "Successful"
3. All Java applications work as before (ide/dbms/email/etc)
4. Tried to launch a java applet in Chrome (or Safari)
5. Message in the applet area "Missing Plugin =>".  *click it*
6. Error that the '`JRE is not installed, click ok to open page...`'.
7. Click [OK] but no page opens. Assume this is because the JRE is actually already installed.
8. Try from command line (`/usr/bin/javaws`):

When I try `/usr/bin/javaws` from the command line I get this output, plus the standard install-a-jre popup.

```
[~] /usr/bin/javaws  (or just [~] javaws)
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
```

– but the JRE is present –

```
[~] /usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

– Java apps do run.

#### Java executables

```
[~] ll -s /usr/bin/java*
/usr/bin/java@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
/usr/bin/javac@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
/usr/bin/javadoc@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javadoc
/usr/bin/javah@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javah
/usr/bin/javap@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javap
/usr/bin/javaws@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws
```

---

I heard that it may be possible to install the Java 7 [JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html#requirements) (including a JRE) to regain preferences and enable switching.  If that is the only course of action I will do it, but I would much prefer `JAVA_HOME` to work properly with Java 6 **without** Java 7.

Apple's Java Preferences utility is no longer applicable – Apple's most recent update for Java for OS X removes the utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [About Java for OS X 2012-006](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493) (article HT5493, modified 2012-10-16) Apple gives a related article:

- [Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) (article HT5559, modified 2012-10-22).

Please run all four commands. The fourth should re-enable Java SE 6 Web Start.

Comment: That appears to work.  Still testing other stuff.  The page sparkles with references such as "if, after installing Java for OS X 2012-006 and Java 7", and I read of problems with it (here as well), so it didn't look like it applied.  But, it does, even if you don't install Java7. Also, try to avoid basically writing a new question when you edit.  We see them as our content, not community (right or wrong).  SO is less overbearing, but edits there seem by-fiat and based on personal taste.

Comment: Sorry, the intention wasn't to overbear, I tried hard to keep the essence of the question whilst making uppermost the key points etc.. Feel free to revert or even better, make your own edit. You make very good points about Apple's document – I'll request an improvement. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for more applets I have tried.  In the start I just tried one.  The most important (citrix) still has an issue that might be because of the update, but I think that is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks again. Incidentally if you find that the Citrix applet works with an EA Java 8, maybe add that one under [Reasons to prefer Java 8 early access (instead of both Java 6 Update 37 and Java 7 Update 9) for the JRE (but not the Java applet plug-in)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/70535/8546). Or if that Citrix applet requires something less than Java 6 Update 37, there's [Which browsers with an integral Java runtime environment (JRE) can run that JRE on Mountain Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72675/8546) but I suspect that the answer there will be a simple "None.".

Comment: All I know right now is that all browsers say they can't find the plugin (it was installed before.) The uninstaller says it finished successfully.  Reinstalling always says there is a newer version on the computer already.  So I'm stuck on citrix, but I think that is their fault at this point.  The Citrix Receiver standalone works fine.

Comment: Article linked, HT5559, worked for me to enable java web start on OS X Lion.

Comment: can't get this to work with Mountain Lion. Ran all commands, and I just got the "More Info" dialog that says to go to Oracle for the latest Java 7. java -version says 1.6.0

Comment: Here is what I did to fix Java Web Start:
http://oligofren.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/java-78-wreaking-havoc-with-java-web-start-in-mountain-lion/

Comment: @oligofren for reference, in Open Radar: [after the re-enabling routine for Apple's Java SE 6 Internet plug-in, the plug-in is reportedly missing](http://openradar.appspot.com/262459255)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with javaws with this:

1. I went into the `/usr/bin` directory:

   ```
   cd /usr/bin/
   ```
2. Just in case made a backup copy of the existing javaws:

   ```
   sudo mv javaws ./javaws.ORIGINAL
   ```
3. Create a new link to a javaws file that I found when searching my file system (probably create on a previous installation of Java):

   ```
   sudo ln -s /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javaws ./javaws
   ```

Et voilà! javaws start working again!

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked "Enable applet plug-in and Web Start Applications" in "Java Preferences" ??

http://support.zipform.com/zf6/KBA-01629.asp

Comment: This is removed in ML (10.8), hence the problem and tag and title.

Comment: Well - it is only removed i ML if you have upgraded to JRE/JDK 7, and as I read the problem described, then it is still JRE/JDK 6 that is been used.

Comment: It is removed when upgrading to 10.8.2 as I did. I am fairly sure other versions of 10.8 are also affected.  I have never installed JDK/JRE 7.  This was apparent the moment the upgrade was complete.  Lost me access to citrix until I can get them to allow reciever access.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68743/mountain-lion-10-8-2-java-preferences-has-disappeared , and google - https://www.google.com/search?q=mountain+lion+removes+java+preferences

Comment: No, the OS X 10.8.2 update didn't remove the Java 6 setup on your system - but the Java update 2012-006 where you got the JRE/JDK 6 update 37 did that - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493

Comment: You are right. I don't know what I was thinking, i'm sorry about that. It must have been something I ate.  Even my question mentions the update as doing it, not ML.  I think I just installed them back-to-back basically.  If you edit the question (however briefly) I'll fix my foolish vote.